# C# - Determine the focused RichTextBox in a Split Container of the Active MDI Child

Tags: c#, richtextbox, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a Form (Form2) that contains a Split Container, the RichTextBox is on the Left Panel and the WebBroswer is on the Right Panel.

I am showing the Form as a child of a MDIParent Form 1. What I wanted to do is copy the selected text of the active MDI Child. However due to the RichTextBox being inside a Split Container, I cannot target the RichTextBox and it returns nothing.

```
Form activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;  

if (activeChild != null)  
{    
    try  
    {  
        RichTextBox theBox = (RichTextBox)activeChild.ActiveControl;  
        if (theBox != null)  
        {  
            // Put the selected text on the Clipboard.  
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(theBox.SelectedText);      
        }
    }  
    catch  
    {  
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to Copy to Clipboard");  
    } 
}
```

The result is, the Message Box shows so that means I wasn't able to target the RTB properly. How can I get the current active RTB?

Comment: What is the value of `activeChild.ActiveControl`? Is it the SplitContainer?

Comment: @RufusL yes it is the Split Container.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ActiveControl` being returned from the child form is the `SplitContainer` control, then we will need to go one level deeper and get the `ActiveControl` from that container in order to finally get the `RichTextBox` control. Note that we have to check for the object types and null along the way, in case a different control may be selected.

Here's one way to get the rich text box text (or an empty string if it's not selected):

```
var childSplitContainer = this.ActiveMdiChild?.ActiveControl is SplitContainer
    ? (SplitContainer)activeChildForm.ActiveControl
    : null;

var splitContainerRTB = childSplitContainer?.ActiveControl is RichTextBox
    ? (RichTextBox)childSplitContainer.ActiveControl
    : null;

Clipboard.SetDataObject(splitContainerRTB?.Text ?? string.Empty);
```